# WordPress hook to call a function in dashboard other than admin

Tags: wordpress, hook

Is there any WordPress hook that can be called on dashboard other than admin.

i have this hook

`add_action('admin_head','upgrade_notification_free_user');`

it works fine for the admin account but when i login from another account it do not fires.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Faisal, glad to see you've solved the problem, which part of my answer helped you?

Comment: 'admin_init' did job for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the WordPress Code Reference the '[admin_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_head/)' action should fire in the head section of all admin pages.

Alternatively you could try '[admin_init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init)' or '[in_admin_footer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/in_admin_footer)' depending on what your function is trying to accomplish.

Try installing the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin it will show you all hooks that are fired when a page is loaded. Make sure to use a special authentication cookie - see [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/faq/) for details - so non-administrators will also see Query Monitor's output.